# Eclipse Angular JS HTML file doesn't give Completion feature

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

I could not get completion for my angular js eclipse based file. I know there could be lot of tutorials for setting up proper angular js for eclipse. But i read and followed the same and didn't worked still.
I also followed official link-> [Angular JS Eclipse Github setup link][1]

I installed, “Angular JS” from “Eclipse->Help Menu->Eclipse Marketplace”

It got installed and restarted.

Then, Eclipse->New->Static web project

Then, Convert the project to Angular. Right click Project, Configure-> Convert to Angular JS project

Then, Adding new html files. Right click Project, New->HTML file

Simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div>
            <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
                <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine. Runs in the browser well.

My problem is, why does not it show the completion help when I type on "ng-" and use control + space in mac eclipse ? When I move cursor on "ng", it gives help of "div" tag rather than "ng" help. I want to just type "ng-" and get the list of available methods by just press control + space in mac eclipse

I can understand that there is some angular installation problem. But, none of the existing solution solved my issue.

Comment: Is {{name}} is highlighted?